# Validation of Date in MVC Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have the following gridview code and I am trying to do some basic validation on my dates. As you can see I have a start date and end date and I need to validate them so that StartDate <= EndDate. Is there a simple way to add this validation to the code below?

```
Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "gvActiveScheduledAnnouncements";
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.KeyFieldName = "AnnouncementId";

    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "ActiveScheduledAnnouncementsPartial" };

    settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditForm;

    settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "AddNewAnnouncement" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "UpdateActiveScheduledAnnouncement" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "DeleteActiveScheduledAnnouncement" };

    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.Caption = "Announcement Text";
        c.FieldName = "Text";

        c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.Memo;
        c.EditFormSettings.ColumnSpan = 2;

        c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.Memo;
        var memo = c.PropertiesEdit as MemoProperties;
        memo.Rows = 3;
    });

    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.Caption = "Start Date";
        c.FieldName = "StartDate";


        c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.DateEdit;
    });

    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.Caption = "End Date";
        c.FieldName = "EndDate";

        c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.DateEdit;
    });

    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.Caption = "Display Status";
        c.FieldName = "DisplayStatus";

        c.EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });
})
.Bind(Model)
.Render();
```

Comment: Which validation do you want: client-side or server-side? If server-side is used, place a if-condition in controller code, otherwise use JS/jQuery with `MVCxClientGridView` methods which reads date field on edit form, then check their values using if-condition.

Comment: Honestly I am interested in both but haven't been able to figure out how to do either so if you can provide an example either way I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Validation can be done from the controller with the data in raw or from the view with razor or js.

**I recommend you do it in the driver so just render it in the view.**

Comment: We aren't using razor unfortunately, it's just an ascx partial view page. Could you give me an example of how I would accomplish it "in the driver"? thanks!

Comment: @DeCo Waiting till hitting the Controller is a horrible idea.  Yes, you could do it, however, it creates an unnecessary trip to the server.  It is better practice to do a validation check on the client side.  That is a major part of MVC in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to enable a custom Validation Setting.  The following link is one way to do it: [Link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q374445)

Another would be to manually check for that field during the edit process via jQuery or JavaScript.  In doing either of the above, just be watching for when the edit process begins, then find the controls to be watching via jQuery.  Check their values when hitting save (or even when a second date (Start or End) is added) and alert the user if they are invalid.